# using selenium to interact with popup print dialogue box not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to interact(set options like page size etc) on a print dialogue box that pops up after hitting a print button on a webpage. My attempt at the code is :

win_before = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2b9T.png)/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button').click() # clicks the print button on webpage
time.sleep(2)
popup = 0
for handle in driver.window_handles:
   if handle != win_before:
      popup = handle
      break
driver.switch_to.window(popup)
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('print-preview-app')")
print(elem.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

at this point since the program has switched to the popped up dialogue box window , we should be able to interact with elements within the box using selenium  methods  but i have had no success. So i switched to using query selector this way and i still cannot locate any elements.
[Html of the print dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2b9T.png)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using alerts, it could be that the new window is an alert and swap to this something like `Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();` instead of a browser window. If it is a browser element you could try Actions or javascript to move to the element before clicking and working with this element. Sorry if this isn't what you need - hope this helps.

Comment: driver.switch_to.window() worked for me and I've managed to change paper size to A5 and some other settings using js paths . Now the only remaining thing is to interact and press "save" in the system's print dialogue box that pops up. Any suggestions about that? I was wondering if pywin32 could help?